# Allocation exception in Eigen::SparseMatrix::reserve

Tags: c++, eigen

I am using Eigen for a large, sparse matrix of (in this example) dimensions 2e8 x 1e6, which has at most 128 elements on each row. In accordance with the [docs](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html), I call `reserve` to allocate memory before inserting the non-zero elements. For large matrices, `reserve` throws a `std::bad_alloc` exception.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>

int main()
{
  typedef Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, Eigen::RowMajor, long long int> SparseMat;

  size_t n = 1000000, r = 200;
  SparseMat T (r*n, n);

  std::cerr << "Reserving memory" << std::endl;

  size_t q = 128;
  T.reserve(Eigen::VectorXi::Constant(r*n, q));

  std::cerr << "Ready to start inserting elements..." << std::endl;
}
```

Compiling with `clang++` or `g++` on Ubuntu 16.04 throws the `std::bad_alloc` exception at run time:

```
$ clang++ -march=native -O3 -isystem eigen-3.3.3 test_sparse.cpp -o test_sparse && ./test_sparse
Reserving memory
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
[1]    26431 abort      ./test_sparse
```

Reducing the number of non-zero elements per row to `q = 49` or below runs fine. Setting `q = 50` or above produces the error. Similar tests hold for the matrix size.

Notice also that I am explicitly using the 64-bit integer type for the `StorageIndex`. It is my understanding that 64-bit should be plenty to index the 1.28e8 non-zero elements in this matrix, because it is smaller than 2^63-1 = 9.2e18. In the limit, it should even be sufficient to index a dense matrix of this size (2e8 x 1e6 = 2e14 < 9.2e18).

Hence my questions are:

1. Am I correct to assume that the 64-bit `StorageIndex` is sufficient
   for these matrix dimensions?
2. If so, is this a bug or is something wrong in my example?
3. If not, I also tried `__int128_t`, but that produces the following
   compiler error: 
   `EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT(NumTraits<StorageIndex>::IsSigned,THE_INDEX_TYPE_MUST_BE_A_SIGNED_TYPE);`
   How can I add the relevant traits?
4. Finally, can this issue be circumvented, using for example the initialisation from triplets?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Eigen but how many bytes of data are you trying to reserve and do you have enough memory?

Comment: Good point, my 64GB is insufficient for 128 elements per row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::bad_alloc` normally means you ran out of memory and given you are trying to allocate ~100GB that doesn't surprise me

`T.reserve(Eigen::VectorXi::Constant(r*n, q));` allocates r * n * q=1000000*200*128 floats in memory.

Not very many machines at the current state of technology can provide so much memory

Comment: You make an excellent point, 128 floats per row do indeed not fit in the 64GB RAM I have available, though the example for `q = 50` should (~37GB). Any suggestions on how to work around this (other than getting more memory)?

Comment: @ChD Is that a contiguous chunk of memory? If so, you may not have enough available memory due to fragmentation.

Comment: Yes, I think it is. Also, the 37GB for q = 50 would be for the values (matrix coefficients) only, while their indices will take up an equal amount of space. I had been using q = 8 for some time, even on 8GB systems, and memory was never the bottleneck. But for the extended matrix it clearly is. Thanks for pointing me to it. I'll need to rethink the problem formulation :-)

Comment: Depending on your application you might consider working without matrices: [eigen-matrix-free-solver](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__MatrixfreeSolverExample.html).